# Como conectar a AWS desde codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, aws

Resulta que estoy creando web services para después poder consumirlos, el tema es que la base de datos la tengo en Amazon Web Services y aparentemente algo impide a que yo me conecte a ella.

Baje desde codeIgniter.com el zip, lo descomprimí y empece a configurar en la carpeta config/ el archivo database.php. Solo agregue los datos requeridos:

```
-hostname:'chompiras.c24z******.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com'  
-username:'chompiras'  
-password:'dh7a76a5a******' 
-database: 'chompiras'
```

y el **dbdriver** lo deje tal cual: 'mysqli' bien sabemos que mysql esta fuera de uso.

Les mostraria mi código de controlador y modelo pero probe con las credenciales de otra base de datos y funciona perfecto.

donde subi la carpeta? a un servidor de smart, (no a AWS) ya que ese es de producción y es delicado trabajar los datos, pero con las credenciales bien puestas no debería de haber error!

Hago las pruebas con POST y arroja lo siguiente:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'chompiras.c24z******.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (110 "Connection timed out")
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 201
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/Chompirasc/public_html/wsatencion/index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

y tambien:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa si la aplicación funciona localmente (en tu equipo) apuntando a la base de datos. Si te logras conectar, realiza un telnet desde el servidor en el cual está alojada la aplicación:

```
telnet chompiras.c24z******.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
```

Si el telnet te indica que no te puedes conectar, debe existir alguna regla del firewall que impide la comunicación entre estos servidores. Podrías intentar a deshabilitarlo

Otras cosas que no están de más chequear: dirección del host, nombre de usuario, contraseña, nombre de la base de datos y puerto de conexión.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda configurar los Security Groups de tus instancias para que puedan recibir y enviar trafico por el puerto 3306.

aca puedes ver como configurarlo:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html